# How can I create a plot like this in mathematica?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I think this is called a caterpillar plot. The dot is the mean and the lines represent a 95% confidence interval.

On the x axis there are several different test cycles, the red line is the true value.

[image]

Comment: There's also [BoxWhiskerChart](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoxWhiskerChart.html)

Comment: @Jens I know, but a Boxplot indicates the median not the mean.

Comment: Related: [(15671)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15671/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`ErrorListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ErrorBarPlots/ref/ErrorListPlot.html) as described in: [How to : Add Error Bars to Charts and Plots](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/AddErrorBarsToChartsAndPlots.html).
(This might be considered "easily found" however I don't believe "caterpillar plot" would find it.)

The first example from the documentation:

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]

ErrorListPlot[Table[{i, RandomReal[{0.2, 1}]}, {i, 10}]]
```

[image]

---

By the way if you find that the error bars are being cut off by the edges of the plot you can use [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Show.html) with a [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotRange.html) of `All`:

```
ErrorListPlot[Table[{i, RandomReal[{1, 3}]}, {i, 10}]];

Show[%, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The fact that the error bars are not taken into consideration for the plot range in `ErrorListPlot` itself might be considered a bug.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a cheat using `BoxWhiskerChart`. The error bars are quantiles (0.05, 0.95) and not symmetric confidence interval. It is not ideal wrt placement of mean marker.

Using:

```
rv = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[10, 3], {20, 10}];
BoxWhiskerChart[rv, {{"MeanMarker", Style[\[FilledSmallCircle], 20], 
   Blue}}, Method -> {"BoxRange" -> (Quantile[#, {0.05, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5,
         0.95}, {{1, -1}, {0, 1}}] &)}, ChartStyle -> White, 
 GridLines -> {None, {{4, Dashed}, 10, {16, Dashed}}}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Here is an example using $\mu \pm 1.96 \sigma/\sqrt{n}$ to illustrate how you can adapt:

```
fun[d_] := {#1 - 1.96 #2, #3, #3, #3, #1 + 1.96 #2} & @@ {Mean[d], 
   StandardDeviation[d]/Sqrt[Length@d], Median[d]}
BoxWhiskerChart[rv, {{"MeanMarker", Style[\[FilledSmallCircle], 20], 
   Blue}}, Method -> {"BoxRange" -> (fun@# &)}, ChartStyle -> White, 
 GridLines -> {None, {{4, Dashed}, 10, {16, Dashed}}}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Red]
```

yielding:

[image]