# How to draw a distribution plot (dotplot?) like this in mathematica?

Tags: plotting, graphics, packing

I believe I've seen this answered already here in Stack Exchange but I could not find it again, so here I am asking, hoping that someone knows this other post I am referring to.

Here are examples of the kind of plots I'm talking about (not sure what the proper name would be):

[image]

[image: description]
<sub>(source: [hulinks.co.jp](http://blog.hulinks.co.jp/2013/08/09/SDP2.png))</sub>

Comment: Isn't it just plain ListPlot?

Comment: Consider perhaps [`DistributionChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributionChart.html)?

Comment: That's similar but I thing I've seen something better: [**15678**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15678/5478)

Comment: I am pretty sure I have seen someone posting code to do this. What is special about those plots is the neat horizontal arrangement of points. In the examples above it might not seem that complicated to achieve the same results as shown, but when the data has points whose y-values are rarely exactly the same the horizontal placing needs to be smart to make it look nice.

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DotPlot.html

Comment: Awesome Lou, thanks! That's it. If you post an answer I will gladly accepted it, as it is the one I was looking for.